# Redirection of URL containing dot

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have mistakenly created URLs containing dots in them. In order to update dot with '-' I have updated all the URLs in the database and meanwhile I have added the following line to my .htaccess

```
# Don't rewrite any URIs ending with a file extension (ending with .[xxxx])
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,5}$
```

Now is there any way I can add a RewriteRule or condition in the .htaccess so that all urls containing dot can be redirected by replacing dot with '-' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is very simple. All you're during is matching before and after the `.` using capture groups and then just use the backrefences to create the new URL with the `-`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2 [R=301,L]
```

*Let me know how this works out*.